# Type error when accessing Django request.POST

Tags: python, django, pycharm, typeerror

I'm attempting to build an XML document out of `request.POST` data in a Django app:

```
ElementTree.Element("occasion", text=request.POST["occasion"])
```

PyCharm is giving me an error on the `text` parameter saying `Expected type 'str', got 'Type[QueryDict]' instead`. I only bring up PyCharm because I know its type checker can be overzealous sometimes. However, I haven't been able to find anything about this issue specifically.

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I try to silence this error?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not posting anything unusual, like json, `request.POST['occasion']` should return a string, either the field 'occasion' or the last value of the list submitted with that name (or an error, if empty. Use request.POST.get('occasion') to avoid).

There are apparently some httprequest [related issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37457/Does-not-understand-Django-HttpRequest-objects) with pycharm, but the way to doublecheck if this is happening here would be to print out and/or type check `request.POST['occasion']` prior to that line to make sure of what it returns, eg:

```
occasion = request.POST['occasion']
print(type(occasion), occasion)
ElementTree.Element("occasion", text=occasion)
```

In the last line, using a variable assigned ahead of time might be a simple way to remove the pycharm error without turning off warnings, depending on your tolerance for extra code.

Comment: PyCharm says `request.POST["occasion"]` is of type `Type[QueryDict]`.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems PyCharm doesn't realize that the `self` argument to `request.POST.get` doesn't need to be provided. Yea, seems this is a PyCharm issue.

Comment: @AAM111 can you provide us information on what you are putting into 'occasion'?

Comment: It should be a string. It's the results from a `<input type="text">`.

Comment: I updated the answer with a code snippet  to show more clearly what I meant.  If the `print(type(occasion), occasion)` line shows it's a string, that's pretty conclusive that it's a pycharm problem, not your code.